# Hidden category

Tags: python, blogs, pelican

I would like to hide a whole category on my blog using Pelican. Is there any way to accomplish this, making it accessible only via URL address?

Comment: Isn't that what `status: hidden` is for? See e.g. http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#pages

Comment: similar result `status: draft` - [Publishing drafts](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#publishing-drafts). But both hide only single page/article. Maybe you will have to create own templates to filter category.

Comment: Well, `status: hidden` is only for pages and things that I would like to hide are articles in one category. If I use `status: draft` I will not have the category that connects articles, I will have only hidden articles.

Comment: Where is it showing up that you don't want to see it? You should be able to modify your templates for this, e.g. in index.html: `{% if (article.category|string() != "secret") %}
            <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to {{ article.title|striptags }}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}`